# Toshiba NB305-10N

Tags: windows, windows-7

I have this computer that I bought with Win 7. It was extremely slow and was using around 97% of the memory most of the time. As the machine only has one slot for Ram and this was filled with a 1gb stick, I decided to upgrade to the maximum for the machine which is 2gb. I bought RAM that was recommended for the computer and the only difference that I can see is the the new memory is 2Rx8 at 8500S whereas the old memory is 1Rx8 at 2500S but the machine just will not start with the new memory.
I have tried 2 different sticks, thinking that perhaps one was faulty but the result is the same.
Do you have any ideas why this should be?

Comment: Sad but true.. even 2gb is going to be painful.

Comment: If Toshiba matched the 2 GB with a 5400 rpm hard drive, no memory upgrade will save it.